# How do I notate an alternate trill?

Tags: trills

I have read in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trill_(music)) about the alternative trill. However it does not show as a symbol. How do I notate the trill that indicates that a lower note than the one on the sheet should be played in the trill?

Comment: Piedpiper's answer is correct, but you should always write the trill based on the lower note in the first place.

Comment: Don't get the impression that there are only two kinds. The overall topic is "ornaments, "and there are millions of them; various people in the baroque and Classical periods filled entire books with various varieties. If you have very specific wishes about the timing and style, it might be best to write them out.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is not the case. The written note should be the primary (i.e., melody) note, and the "trill" note the decorative one.

Comment: @Aaron not sure what your point is.  Is this about the style where a trill ends short of the written note and the performer holds the written note?  If you want that *plus* trilling down,  I would strongly suggest writing, e.g.,  a trilled half-note tied to an eighth-note at the upper pitch.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Aaron's point seems to be that sheet music isn't just instructions for performance. You should indicate what the note is conceptually, as part of the harmony. If you wrote a G chord and had the D trill down to a C#, you shouldn't notate a C# with a grace note. Just like you shouldn't notate a C natural  if you're writing a G# major chord.

Answer (score 4):

When notating ornaments, the "main" note — the one that is part of the melody even if the ornament were removed — must be notated explicitly, with the ornament notation added to it.

The assumption with trill indications is that the trill will involve the main note and the note above.<sup>1</sup> A trill from the main note downward should be expressly indicated, as there is no symbol specific to it. This can be done in a variety of ways. I rather like @rfbw's parenthetical note solution, but there are two others which are more common.

1. Add a footnote. This allows, either in text or by notation, for the indication of how the trill should be played.
2. Add an ossia explicitly notating (some portion of) the trill.

Both of these options are unambiguous and will preserve the intrepretive importance of notating the main note.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless otherwise indicates, the "note above" will be the next diatonic note. For a chromatic "note above", an accidental is included above the main note (and below any ***tr*** indication).

Comment: Ok that's important to know, I've changed the answered status of my question because it appears the answer from PiedPiper is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

A trill to a lower note is equivalent to a trill from the lower note to the upper one with a preceding grace note, so that is how it is normally notated.

From the book ["Behind Bars"](http://www.behindbarsnotation.co.uk/) by Elaine Gould (p.138):

> A grace note may specify when the starting note is other than the written note

For example, if you want to trill from A to G, this is the way to notate it:
[image]

Note: starting a trill from the upper note was the default during the baroque era, and this persisted until well into the classical period.

Comment: @AndyBonner - These days, Musescore plays all grace notes placed before larger notes on the beat, not just before, including the slashed grace notes. (I recall that Musescore 1.0 didn't.)

Comment: @Dekkadeci Noted, though unless an OP specifies otherwise, I have to assume they're talking about what humans will do (*if* they know the difference). And with the warning that all ornaments have to be interpreted in light of who wrote them and where and when, and there are exceptions. Also, crap, I got it completely backwards. Deleting and re-commenting...

Comment: @Toma, Note that this will also make certain implications about the timing of the notes. The little A with the slash through it will fall just slightly before the beat; the G will be on the beat and receive a bit more emphasis than the A. If you take away the slash, then the A is an appoggiatura, which is its own type of ornament. The performer would place it exactly on the beat, hold it a bit longer than the other notes in the trill, and emphasize it a bit. If you want neither one, there are also other options, like a two-note alternating tremolo.

Comment: @AndyBonner The fact that music notation software might play the first note before the beat is irrelevant. Any experienced player knows that this is a trill starting on the upper note.

Comment: This notation will produce the technically correct result, but not the musically correct one. In OP's case, A is the "main" note and G the decorate one. The notation here indicates that G is the primary note and A the decorate one. This has potentially signifiant implications for interpretation.

Comment: @PiedPiper I think you've misunderstood Gould's comment. She's only addressing the note immediately preceding the trill. That note is sometimes different that the two notes involved in the trill itself.

Comment: @Aaron I haven't misunderstood Gould's comment. The preceding note can be a completely different note, but very often it's the secondary trill note. The notation is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134433/discussion-between-aaron-and-piedpiper).

Comment: It has always seemed to me that Gould was a prescriptivist, being as interested in creating standard rules as much as actually describing what is out there. I'm not a fan of that approach to sheet music, as it is more a language that evolved over time than a set of rules. And, sure, languages have style guides, but, if an author believes that something would be clearer or otherwise better written another way, that is considered fine. The same should be true of music. I thus don't actually consider Gould to be an authority. Just  a style guide.

Comment: I'd like to note that the grace note isn't a good solution if it carries with it a change in beat. The trill should be the same as an upwards trill, no change in emphasis, speed or beat placement. Just ornamented to the lower note. I find it easiest to write tr and add a downward arrow, but I was expecting there to be a solid convention and I'm surprised that this even is a topic for debate.

Comment: @Toma This notation is used in practice far more often than any of the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

To indicate, that the secondary note is not the upper neighbor in the scale, notate either a **two-tone alternating tremolo** (as mentioned earlier in a comment by @AndyBonner) or a **pitched trill** (as suggested in *Behind Bars* by Elaine Gould, although the term 'pitched trill' seems to stem from the LilyPond community):

[image: measured two-tone tremolo and unmeasured pitched trill]

Keep in mind, that the tremolo could be interpreted either as a free tremolo or a measured tremolo. The measured tremolo would be an abbreviation for strictly rhythmic notes – 32nd notes (demisemiquavers) in this case. The pitched trill does not imply a strict rhythm.

Comment: I guess the second bar is an established convention? But I've never seen it before, and TBH wouldn't know how to interpret it ("Is it a kind of concluding grace before the next note?"). As for measured/unmeasured tremolo, sometimes a fast tempo makes unmeasured obvious, but there's no harm in adding a text note to specify.

Comment: @PiedPiper Well, if you find it typographically ugly: This is just the output of LilyPond, without any tweaking (\pitchedTrill d''2 \startTrillSpan a'). 
I dislike the notation of note value in the tremolo notation. I always have to sort out that these two half notes take up the duration of one half note.